Handling USDT on TRON Transactions with Separate Resource Payer and Sender in Tronweb
Is it possible to send a USDT transaction from one address using TronWeb, while having another address pay for the ENERGY and BANDWIDTH costs? If it's possible, how should I handle signing the transaction with the private keys of both the sending address and the resource-paying address?
